# Postfix sends a mail to Apache every 5 minutes

Tags: linux, apache, postfix-mta

I don't remember how I've configured my Postfix. Today I saw logs `/var/log/mail.log` and noticed that **Postfix sends a mail to Apache every 5 minutes**.

1. I googled it, there are different problems with different apps, but my Postfix setup sends a mail  locally to Apache(www-data user) instead.
2. I opened up crontab -l and there was only a certbot updater, there is nothing related to Postfix.
3. Also I've been running `sudo watch 'netstat --program --numeric-hosts --numeric-ports --extend | grep -E ":25|postfix|smtp"'` for about 5 minutes and I didn't see any outgoing activity.
4. Lastly, I could not see a mail message by running `sudo postcat -q A4A928A015F` because all I've got is a queue id, but it's being removed very quickly as soon as mail was sent.

Here's my logs `/var/log/mail.log`:

```
Jul 18 20:00:01 ubuntu postfix/pickup[202465]: A4A928A015F: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Jul 18 20:00:01 ubuntu postfix/cleanup[204709]: A4A928A015F: message-id=<20230718170001.A4A928A015F@ubuntu>
Jul 18 20:00:01 ubuntu postfix/qmgr[202466]: A4A928A015F: from=<www-data@ubuntu>, size=570, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 18 20:00:01 ubuntu postfix/local[204711]: A4A928A015F: to=<www-data@ubuntu>, orig_to=<www-data>, relay=local, delay=0.47, delays=0.39/0.02/0/0.07, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Jul 18 20:00:01 ubuntu postfix/qmgr[202466]: A4A928A015F: removed
Jul 18 20:05:01 ubuntu postfix/pickup[202465]: EB3048A015F: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Jul 18 20:05:01 ubuntu postfix/cleanup[205437]: EB3048A015F: message-id=<20230718170501.EB3048A015F@ubuntu>
Jul 18 20:05:02 ubuntu postfix/qmgr[202466]: EB3048A015F: from=<www-data@ubuntu>, size=570, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 18 20:05:02 ubuntu postfix/local[205439]: EB3048A015F: to=<www-data@ubuntu>, orig_to=<www-data>, relay=local, delay=0.35, delays=0.29/0.02/0/0.04, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Jul 18 20:05:02 ubuntu postfix/qmgr[202466]: EB3048A015F: removed
```

**How do I know which script does the job and why does my Postfix send something to www-data?**

Comment: Does the mailbox (perhaps at `/var/mail/www-data`) exist, and is there anything in it?

Comment: The messages say "to=<www-data@ubuntu>, orig_to=<www-data>" and "delivered to mailbox". Check the mailbox of `www-data`, e.g. `less /var/mail/www-data`. Is there a `cron` job for user `www-data` that runs every 5 minutes?

Comment: @WanderNauta @Bodo `/var/mail/www-data` exists and shows me that there is a cronjob on www-data `php -f /var/www/nextcloud/cron.php`, but I've deleted nextcloud recently. I think my problem is solved, thank you guys.